# Ruby Client Library

Tags: library, ruby

I've started a Ruby client library project on GitHub. There's no code there, but I will be hacking on it all weekend and welcome contributions.

#### Sample Code

```
client = StackOverflow::Client.new(version, apiKey, urlClient, protocol)
client.questions.recent.each do |q|
 ...
end

client.users.find(1190)
# => <StackOverflow::User name='James A. Rosen'>
```

(Syntax is not yet finalized, but this should provide the right idea.)

#### About

The project will use [RSpec](http://rspec.info/) for testing and either [Rack-Client](http://github.com/halorgium/rack-client) or [HTTParty](http://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty) for API calls. It will try to use [Arel](http://github.com/nkallen/arel)-like syntax for querying.

#### License

SOFlow is released under the MIT license

#### Download

You will be able to install soflow as a ruby gem with `gem install soflow`, or download the source from the [git repository](http://github.com/jamesarosen/SOFlow).

#### Platform

SOFlow is being developed primarily on Ruby 1.9 (MRI), but cross-ruby compatibility is a goal.

#### Contact

Bugs and feature requests should be made as issues on the above repository.

#### Code

Code is available at the repository listed above.

Comment: Was just thinking about doing a notifier using ruby, so I'm looking forward to this.  I'm relatively new to ruby, but I'll contribute if I can once you have some stuff in place.

Comment: Anything ever come of this?

Comment: Does this still exist? The GitHub repo link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

You might also want to use [Hashie](http://github.com/intridea/hashie). One of the [best twitter clients](http://twitter.rubyforge.org/) for ruby uses it, and the resulting interface is very clean and easy to use. I've wrapped over Delicious rss api with it in less than 60 lines.